# problem with load env files for each apps in nest microservice

Tags: node.js, nestjs-config

I have nest application which contains two apps : auth and reservations
I want to create .env file for each of them
I define a .enf file in each folder but in configService i still get error
but when i create a .env file in main root directory every thing wents well

```
[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do6x6.png)

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOhj9.png)

[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLiJ5.png)

[pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPZud.png)`
```

I am wathing a course about microservice from udemy (michle gray)
in authentication section he use docker but u prefer to dont use docker